# How to make button in Python Tkinter stay pressed until another one is pressed

Tags: python, button, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to find a way Tkinter to make the `Start` button stay pressed until I press the `Stop` button.

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox


class MainWindow(Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.master.title("input")
        self.master.minsize(250, 150)
        self.grid(sticky=E+W+N+S)

        top=self.winfo_toplevel()
        top.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        top.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        for i in range(2):self.rowconfigure(i, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

        self.button0 = Button(self, text="Start", command=self.save, activeforeground="red")
        self.button0.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=2, padx=2, sticky=E+W+N+S)

        self.button1 = Button(self, text="Stop", command=self.stop, activeforeground="red")
        self.button1.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=2, padx=2, sticky=E+W+N+S)

    def save(self):
        pass

    def stop(self):
        pass


if __name__=="__main__":
   d=MainWindow()
   d.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So you can set the relief of the button using its config, this makes it look like it is pressed.

```
def save(self):
    self.button0.config(relief=SUNKEN)
    # if you also want to disable it do:
    # self.button0.config(state=tk.DISABLED)
    #...

def stop(self):
    self.button0.config(relief=RAISED)
    # if it was disabled above, then here do:
    # self.button0.config(state=tk.ACTIVE)
    #...
```

**EDIT**

This doesn't work on Mac OSx apparently. This link shows how in *should* look: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_relief.htm

Comment: Which part doesn't work? I think there may be a platform dependance here, as this works on my Linux box, but not on Mac OSx.

Comment: "dosen't work" is not very informative. What happens? Do you see any errors? Here's a [complete code example to try](https://gist.github.com/11390111)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian It would appear that on MacOSx (at least on 10.7.5 with python 2.7) the button is never depressed and the relief state cannot be set.

Comment: does it fail with both `.config` and `.configure` methods? I've updated [the gist](https://gist.github.com/11390111)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Yes. The state of the button can be set without any problems (an the same goes for hover colours, backgrounds etc.) but the relief appears to be fixed in a raised state.

Comment: I've added [ttk-based variant](https://gist.github.com/zed/11390111#file-leave-button-pressed-ttk-py).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Still no, it alters the highlight colour and the text colour, but not the relief.

Comment: does [`button.state(['pressed', 'disabled'])`](https://gist.github.com/zed/11390111#file-leave-button-pressed-ttk-py) help?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian again no. I suspect there is no straight forward way to do this given the way buttons are rendered on Mac.

Answer (score 4):

If [`Tkinter.Button` doesn't allow to configure its `relief` property](https://gist.github.com/zed/11390111#file-leave-button-pressed-until-stop-py) on your system then you could try [`ttk.Button`-based code](https://gist.github.com/zed/11390111#file-leave-button-pressed-ttk-py) instead:

```
try:
    import Tkinter as tk
    import ttk
except ImportError: # Python 3
    import tkinter as tk
    import tkinter.ttk as ttk

SUNKABLE_BUTTON = 'SunkableButton.TButton'

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("400x300")
style = ttk.Style()

def start():
    button.state(['pressed', 'disabled'])
    style.configure(SUNKABLE_BUTTON, relief=tk.SUNKEN, foreground='green')

def stop():
    button.state(['!pressed', '!disabled'])
    style.configure(SUNKABLE_BUTTON, relief=tk.RAISED, foreground='red')

button = ttk.Button(root, text ="Start", command=start, style=SUNKABLE_BUTTON)
button.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
ttk.Button(root, text="Stop", command=stop).pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

I know its too late and you probably have got an solution, but this this answer might be helpful for others.

The solution is to use  `Radio Button`.The main motive for creation of `Radio Button` is same as your question.

Here's an example from [GeeksforGeeks website](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/radiobutton-in-tkinter-python/#:%7E:text=The%20Radiobutton%20is%20a%20standard,calls%20that%20function%20or%20method.):

```
# Importing Tkinter module
from tkinter import *
# from tkinter.ttk import *

# Creating master Tkinter window
master = Tk()
master.geometry("175x175")

# Tkinter string variable
# able to store any string value
v = StringVar(master, "1")

# Dictionary to create multiple buttons
values = {"RadioButton 1" : "1",
        "RadioButton 2" : "2",
        "RadioButton 3" : "3",
        "RadioButton 4" : "4",
        "RadioButton 5" : "5"}

# Loop is used to create multiple Radiobuttons
# rather than creating each button separately
for (text, value) in values.items():
    Radiobutton(master, text = text, variable = v,
                value = value, indicator = 0,
                background = "light blue").pack(fill = X, ipady = 5)

# Infinite loop can be terminated by
# keyboard or mouse interrupt
# or by any predefined function (destroy())
mainloop()
```

Further, You can create Button Functions and achieve your desired output.